# Hide content when another div is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that allows the user to click an image and receive information associated with the image. I need the information to toggle between the two text areas (so only one body of text is shown at a time). Can anyone help me out with the Javascript for this? Thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".customers").click(function () {
       
        if($(".content1").height() === 0){
             $(".content1").animate({height: "100%"}, 500);
        }else{
            $(".content1").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
        
    });
})


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".landlords").click(function () {
       
        if($(".content2").height() === 0){
             $(".content2").animate({height: "100%"}, 500);
        }else{
            $(".content2").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
        
    });
})
```

```css
.information {  
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.customers {
  display:inline-block;
}

.landlords {
  display:inline-block;
}

.content1 {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}

.content2 {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">
    <div class="customers"><img src="http://cornerstoneparking.portfolio.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Customers.jpg" width="200"></div>
    <div class="landlords"><img src="http://cornerstoneparking.portfolio.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Landlords.jpg" width="200"></div>
    <div class="content1" style="height: 0px;overflow:hidden;">
        Cornerstone Parking provides value for money parking in Brisbane’s CBD and surrounding suburbs. Our turn up and park rates (ie no need to pre-book) are often cheaper than other car park’s online discount rates and you can always be sure of getting a bay in a Cornerstone car park. Our convenient and centrally located CBD car parks are run by our friendly staff and are predominantly located in the Adelaide Street, Ann Street and Creek Street areas. Our car parks offer discounted parking in large bays with ample height clearance. We offer hourly (visitor) parking as well as monthly parking, early bird parking and motorbike parking in most of our car parks.
    </div>
     <div class="content2" style="height: 0px;overflow:hidden;">
       Cornerstone Parking provides a high quality, professional and technology driven car park management service. A part of the Cornerstone Group, our property development and management heritage provides us with a true appreciation of landlord issues. Our parent company backing means that Cornerstone Parking has the appetite and ability to participate in larger parking projects, including the development of new car parks. We provide owners, investors and developers with our car park management, advisory and consultation services.
    </div>
   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need: Only add if statement at the beginning of each onclick event listener.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".customers").click(function () {

        if($(".content2").height() != 0){
            $(".content2").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
       
        if($(".content1").height() === 0){
             $(".content1").animate({height: "100%"}, 500);
        }else{
            $(".content1").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
        
    });
})


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".landlords").click(function () {
        
        if($(".content1").height() != 0){
            $(".content1").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
        if($(".content2").height() === 0){
             $(".content2").animate({height: "100%"}, 500);
        }else{
            $(".content2").animate({height: "0px"}, 500);
        }
        
    });
})
```

```css
.information {  
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}

.customers {
  display:inline-block;
}

.landlords {
  display:inline-block;
}

.content1 {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}

.content2 {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="information">
    <div class="customers"><img src="http://cornerstoneparking.portfolio.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Customers.jpg" width="200"></div>
    <div class="landlords"><img src="http://cornerstoneparking.portfolio.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Landlords.jpg" width="200"></div>
    <div class="content1" style="height: 0px;overflow:hidden;">
        Cornerstone Parking provides value for money parking in Brisbane’s CBD and surrounding suburbs. Our turn up and park rates (ie no need to pre-book) are often cheaper than other car park’s online discount rates and you can always be sure of getting a bay in a Cornerstone car park. Our convenient and centrally located CBD car parks are run by our friendly staff and are predominantly located in the Adelaide Street, Ann Street and Creek Street areas. Our car parks offer discounted parking in large bays with ample height clearance. We offer hourly (visitor) parking as well as monthly parking, early bird parking and motorbike parking in most of our car parks.
    </div>
     <div class="content2" style="height: 0px;overflow:hidden;">
       Cornerstone Parking provides a high quality, professional and technology driven car park management service. A part of the Cornerstone Group, our property development and management heritage provides us with a true appreciation of landlord issues. Our parent company backing means that Cornerstone Parking has the appetite and ability to participate in larger parking projects, including the development of new car parks. We provide owners, investors and developers with our car park management, advisory and consultation services.
    </div>
   

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></div>
```